# How to parse JSON with random fields in Typescript and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Have `Json string` with random fields in `Typescript`( I don't know what kind of fields inside of `json string` or their types). Want parse `json string` to object with default type of fields for example `string`.

Parsing like this: `let values = JSON.parse(this.props.values!)`

Having error when working with React.js, because of type `unknown`. Also can't predefine `interface` because I don't know what inside `json string`

```
Object.entries(values).map(([key, value]) => {
                renderValues = (
                    <>
                        <div className="col-1 text-left p-2" ></div>
                        <div className="col-2 text-right p-2" >{key}</div>
                        <div className="col-9 text-left p-2" >{value}</div>
                    </>)
            })
```

Have error:
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1244, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>'

How in typescript when parsing `json string` to object give to object fields default type or cast object fields to default type?

Comment: The function you pass to [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should return something. `renderValues = something.map(()=>item)`

Comment: problem is that I don't know what types and how many fields I have in json string and I want when I parsing json string to object make all fields for example type of string, because now fields have type of `unknown`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented; can you try the following:

```
renderValues = Object.entries(values).map(
  ([key: string, value: string]) => (
    <>
      <div className="col-1 text-left p-2"></div>
      <div className="col-2 text-right p-2">{key}</div>
      <div className="col-9 text-left p-2">{value}</div>
    </>
  )
);
```

And please read the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) I posted before because you are not using Array.prototype.map correctly.